# why the isblank returned array cannot work with match function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In fact my task is simple, just try to find the index of the first blank cell. 
But my question is why the `ISBLANK` return array cannot work with `MATCH` function, which I suppose it should work. So I guess something I am not aware underneath.

Here is the first version I try to use:
[image: EXAMPLE1]

But it cannot work:

[image: error value]

But the following is working, which I wrap the array returned by `ISBLANK` with `INDEX`:

[image: correct]

So can anyone help to explain why the first one is not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one do not work, because you do not press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an array formula.
If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am totally new to so-called "array formula", why the first need the extra conversion via "C+S+E" but the second not need it?